# Update in PL/SQL Block giving PLS-00103 error

Tags: plsql

I am trying to create a `PL/SQL` block to update a empty column, `is_true`, in a new table `created_table` on the basis of another table, `table1`. The `id` fields on the tables match and there are no rows in `created_table` that doesn't have a corresponding row in `table1`. I'm basing the update on the status column of `table1`, but instead of 'Yes' and 'No', I need it reflected as 'Y' and 'N':

```
created_table:                         expected results:
id | is_true | other columns           id | is_true | other columns
---|---------|--------------           ---|---------|--------------
 1 | null    | ...                      1 | 'Y'     | ...          
 2 | null    | ...                      2 | 'N'     | ...          

table1:
id | status | other columns
---|--------|--------------
 1 | 'Yes'  | ...          
 2 | 'No'   | ...
```

Since `created_table` is very large, I'm trying to update it using a `PL/SQL` procedure, so that in case of failure midway, I'll still have updated rows. The next run of the procedure can then pick up where it previously failed without processing already processed rows.

I've tried testing with this code block:

```
DECLARE
  is_true varchar2 (5) created_table.is_true%type; 
BEGIN
  FOR status IN (SELECT a.status 
                 from table1 a 
                 left join created_table b
                 where and a.id=b.id ) 
  LOOP
        IF  status = 'Yes' THEN
            UPDATE created_table SET is_true= 'Y'
        ELSE
            UPDATE created_table SET is_true= 'N'
                WHERE ROWNUM := status.ROWNUM
        END IF;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Done');
    END LOOP;
END;
```

But it's giving me errors:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: [Rownum](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) doesn't seem to be a real column. What should happen when there's no record in `a` with an `id`, that exists in `created_table`? You seem slightly confused about the use of both `SQL` and `pl/sql`. Can you better express in words what you want to achieve with an example? Also, is it necessary to use a `cursor` in a `pl/sql procedure` or would a single `SQL` suffice?

Comment: Thanks for the response.Our approach is to create a table with the relevant data set and alter the table with an additional column for the status flag. The next step is something I am stuck with - we are trying to set the flag based on the value of a particular column in another table and in it ensure that if the process fails it wont pick up the records already processed.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you without more information in your Question. I wouldn't want to guess, and then post an answer that doesn't apply to the situation.

Comment: I have edited my response.Thanks for the response.Our approach is to create a table with the relevant data set and alter the table with an additional column for the status flag. The next step is something I am stuck with - we are trying to set the flag based on the value of a particular column in another table and in it ensure that if the process fails it wont pick up the records already processed.

Comment: Maybe think of it this way: What information in full would you need to make the program work, if you had no problems with the actual code? I'm not sure what "pick up" means. Does that mean commit the already processed rows or rollback? Kindly update the Question, as the information tend to get lost in comments, and you're less likely to get help when people are confused about the Question. Something like: This is my table, this is my other table. I'd like to have this happen. These are the special circumstances. This is my code. This is the error or this is the wrong result.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question @Scratte

Comment: Is created_table based on table1, so that one can safely assume that there is no id in created_tables, that does not exist is table1? What could cause an error in the middle of processing? Is it a very large table?

Comment: created_table is not based on table1 - all the ids present in created_table are part of table1.its a huge data set for a year and so we are being careful about a process failure in the middle.

Comment: I'd like to edit your Question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had multiple errors:

```
DECLARE
--  is_true varchar2 (5) created_table.is_true%type; -- PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATED_TABLE" when expecting one of the following:
  is_true created_table.is_true%type;
BEGIN
  FOR status IN (SELECT a.status 
                 from table1 a 
--                 left join created_table b  -- ORA-00905: missing keyword
--                 where and a.id=b.id ) 
                 left join created_table b on a.id = b.id)
  LOOP
--        IF  status = 'Yes' THEN -- PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '='
        IF  status.status = 'Yes' THEN
--            UPDATE created_table SET is_true= 'Y' -- ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
            UPDATE created_table SET is_true= 'Y';
        ELSE
            UPDATE created_table SET is_true= 'N'
--                WHERE ROWNUM := status.ROWNUM  -- ORA-00920: invalid relational operator and ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
                WHERE ROWNUM = status.ROWNUM;
        END IF;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Done');
    END LOOP;
END;  -- PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
/
```

The `PLS-00103` is really just telling you that a `/` is missing. After that the remaining error is `PLS-00302: component 'ROWNUM' must be declared`. From "Oracle Database Online Documentation": [rownum is a pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm).

Your `SQL` would update **every** row in the table setting `is_true` to `'Y'` on the first encounter of `status` being `'Yes'`, since you didn't give it a `WHERE` clause. I'm assuming that is not your intent.

There was also **no** `COMMIT` in your `PL/SQL` block, so in effect it would have been the same as running a normal `SQL`.

---

Based on the situation you've described, I made some changes to the code block. This will provide with a limit for how many rows can be processed prior to a `COMMIT`. I set the limit to 5. You should change that to something appropriate. It will not pick up any rows that have empty values for `is_true`, so in effect it will only work on non-processed rows:

```
DECLARE
  commit_counter PLS_INTEGER := 1; -- count commits
  commit_limit   PLS_INTEGER := 5; -- rows for commit limit
  counter        PLS_INTEGER := commit_limit;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (SELECT a.status, a.id 
                FROM created_table b
                JOIN table1 a ON a.id = b.id
               WHERE b.is_true IS NULL) -- do not pick up processed rows
  LOOP
        IF  rec.status = 'Yes' THEN
            UPDATE created_table SET is_true = 'Y'
             WHERE id = rec.id;
        ELSE
            UPDATE created_table SET is_true = 'N'
             WHERE id = rec.id;
        END IF;

        counter := counter - 1;

        IF counter < 1 THEN
          counter := commit_limit; --reset counter
          commit_counter := commit_counter + 1;
          COMMIT;
        END IF;
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT; -- all rows are processed;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(commit_counter || ' COMMITS');
END;
/
```

This will update all the rows in one go, still only updating the "empty" rows:

```
UPDATE created_table b
   SET is_true = (SELECT CASE a.status WHEN 'Yes' THEN 'Y'
                                       ELSE 'N'
                         END 
                    FROM table1 a
                   WHERE a.id = b.id)
 WHERE b.is_true IS NULL;
```